# C# interlocked operations and memory ordering

Tags: c#, multithreading

I understand that two `interlocked` operations on a single variable are ordered. Other than this, is there any ordering guarantee for `interlocked` operations on two different variables?

In c++, we have `memory_order_seq_cst` semantic which guarantees that

> 29.3/3
>
> There shall be a single total order S on all memory_order_seq_cst
>   operations, consistent with the “happens before” order and
>   modification orders for all affected locations, ...

EDIT: If we limit the discussion to x86, there's a memory model called [x86-TSO](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/weakmemory/cacm.pdf) which specifies the ordering between two `LOCK` prefixed operations.

> To execute a LOCK’d instruction, a thread must first
>   obtain the global lock. At the end of the instruction, it
>   flushes its store buffer and relinquishes the lock. While
>   the lock is held by one thread, no other thread can
>   read.

According to the above rule, two interlocked operations will be globally ordered on x86.